# String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, string, exception, indexing

I have a similar problem.This is a snippet of my source:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("results_for_excel.txt");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
String sourceDirectory = "CVs";
File f = new File(sourceDirectory);
String[] filenames = f.list();
Arrays.sort(filenames);
String[] res = new String[filenames.length];
for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + filenames[i]);
}


for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    int beg = filenames[i].indexOf("-");
    int end = filenames[i].indexOf(".");
    res[i] = filenames[i].substring(beg,end);
    System.out.println((i+1)+res[i]);
    writer.write(res[i] + "\n");
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

I get an exception at res[i] = filenames[i].substring(beg,end);
I cant figure what's going on.Thanks in advance:)
P.S I have read all the duplicates but nothing happened:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code after

```
int beg = filenames[i].indexOf("-");
int end = filenames[i].indexOf(".");
```

This will display the filename that is in the wrong format;

```
if (beg == -1 || end == -1)
{
    System.out.println("Bad filename: " + filenames[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
int beg = filenames[i].indexOf("-");
int end = filenames[i].indexOf(".");
```

is returning a `-1`, its possible there's a file which doesn't contain either.

Comment: Changed `Eithor` to `Either`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, because a filename does not contain both '-' and '.'. In that case `indexOf` returns `-1` which is not a valid parameter for `substring`.

Answer (score 1):

Either `beg` or `end` is -1. This means the filename doesn't contain `-` or `.`. Simple as that:)

Answer (score 0):

One of characters in this code

```
int beg = filenames[i].indexOf("-");
int end = filenames[i].indexOf(".");
```

is not found, so either `beg` or `end` equals -1. That's why you got the exception while calling `substring` with negative arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at a KDE file called ".directory".Thank you very very much all of you:)